# Republishing a collection of published papers in a book

Tags: publications, legal-issues

A publisher is interested in republishing a book on a collection of papers published by me and my colleagues. I have secured permissions from publishers of papers to do so. Are there other issues remained?

Comment: Did you get permission from the other authors?  It's not "necessary" so long as you have the permission of the copyright holders, but it's certainly a professional courtesy to do so.

Comment: @ScottSeidman I'd say it rises quite a bit higher than mere "professional courtesy".

Answer (score 2):

Did you get permission from the other authors? It's not "necessary" for the new publisher, so long as you have the permission of the copyright holders, but at the very least, it's certainly a professional courtesy to do so, and possibly a very important thing to do.

Royalty sharing with the other authors might also be indicated, or even legally required.